# how to setup basic environment for react and smart contract deployment

Tags: solidity, environment, truffle

how to setup basic environment for react and smart contract deployment

I am not able to setup environment for below tech stack
basic environment for truffle , solidity ,react app on vs code

Comment: Please make yourself clear! It's a general question, nobody will answer it.

Comment: You first need to read Truffle Docs and YouTube videos, then if you couldn't, you can get there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Truffle is old now.

The stack for setting up a basic environment for react and smart contract deployment would be:

Node.js
React
Hardhat
Web3.js - for interacting with the Ethereum blockchain from within a React application
MetaMask
Test ethers on goreli
Node prodiver - Alchemy
Web3 modal for connect wallet